# About Android Permissions

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I made an Android App, which have some permissions, everything is ok but problem is that when user don't click on Allow or Deny(on Permission Dialog at first time app launch) button with in few seconds(approx 3 to 5 seconds) then my app not functioning properly it's register page, login and some other functions not working, if user click within few seconds then its work properly without any issue, i also check this from Internet but nobody clear my issue please help. FCM token not generating from Firebase.

Error is:-

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Unable to get master token
    java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10493 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId(ITelephony.java:5030)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:1013)
        at com.Abc.AppName.FirebaseInstanceIDService.id(FirebaseInstanceIDService.java:63)
        at com.Abc.AppName.FirebaseInstanceIDService.onTokenRefresh(FirebaseInstanceIDService.java:35)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source:187)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.handleIntent(Unknown Source:306)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Manifest:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Splash:-

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
            };
            if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST);
            } else {             
                  callNextActivity();
            }
        } else {            
              callNextActivity();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {                  
                     callNextActivity();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.permission_denied, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

FirebaseInstanceID:-

```
@Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        device_id = id(this);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs), 0);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("fcm_token", token).apply();
        device_id = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, "");
        Log.e("fcm_token", token + " " + device_id);
        executeMethod();
    }
    public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
        if (uniqueID == null) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.prefs), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            uniqueID = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, null);
            if (uniqueID == null) {
                mngr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {                  
                }
                uniqueID = mngr.getDeviceId();
                Log.e("UNIQUEID", uniqueID);
                sharedPrefs.edit().putString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueID).apply();
            }
        }
        return uniqueID;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to get id of the device in `onTokenRefresh` . This method will be called as soon as the app gets installed and opened first time . By this time your app wont have the permission .

So solution to this problem .

In `onTokenRefresh` just save the token in shared preferences and when you reach the activity ,request for permission and after permission is granted get the token from shared preferences and device id and do your stuff .

Comment: This error only showing in Android Oreo, Nougat or other below is working fine.

Comment: because runtime permission is needed only on android version 6.0+

Answer (score 0):

You can use another activity to request permissions. If user allows, just start your main activity, else kill request activity or show popup to warn user.